# How to Check if Blog Template in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am having trouble checking specifically for just the blog template page (the one that calls the loop in Wordpress). In the settings I don't set static pages for Homepage and Blog. I have a custom template rendered for the homepage. I want to be able to check for the Blog template and not the blog single posts, the homepage or other page templates as I have other custom things going on there.

```
is_page_template() seems to affect other page templates.
is_home() calls my homepage
is_blog() calls my blog posts?
```

Would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... Two ways i think you can check for this

```
//BLOG CHECK
if( (is_archive() || is_author() || is_category() || is_home() || is_tag()) && (get_post_type() === 'post')):
    //DO WHAT YOU WANT
endif;
```

OR

```
if(is_home() && !is_front_page()): // blog check
     ...
endif;
```

Hope it solves it for you.

Comment: Give this link a try : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156624/121298